# Weblogic : How to Download/Upload files from front-end (File Store ?)

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a web application running on Weblogic 12c using Java7 as backend and angularjs in front end.

I want to be able to download/upload one (pdf) file from it.

The basic user cases are :

- The user can click on a button to download the file.
- The user can click a button and pick a local file, this file will then be uploaded and replace the previous one as the downloable file.

There will only be one file.

I've tried to find a solution online and I ended up creating a File Store (with a direct-write policy).
But I haven't found how to download the file when using my application.

Also, I'm not sure this solution will work for my upload case.

How can I et up my application to download/upload this file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filestores are a wholly different concept, used to store JMS messages. Don't let the name confuse you, this is not a usecase for filestores.

Consider this Q for handling the file upload: [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet) - and save the file on a folder in the filesystem. Your WebLogic 12c installation supports servlet 3.0 annotations.